# Elegant way to add a new coordinate to an xarray

Tags: python-xarray

This works but it seems clunky.  Say I want to add a new coordinate to an existing dataset.

```
ds.coords['nextday'] = ('time', [timeVal + np.timedelta64(1,'D') for timeVal in ds['time'].values])
```

I need to pull out the original values, transorm with a comprehension and then stuff them back in as a coord.  Is there a better way?